# How to remove the Authorization header from a http request in QT

Tags: c++, qt, http-headers, httprequest

I want to remove the '**Authorization:** ' header from my GET request fired. QT by default adds it.

Sample of request fired -

GET https://mywebsiteurl.com/remote.php/webdav/3.txt HTTP/1.1

---

**Authorization: Basic Og==**

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) myapp/1.2.1

Connection: Keep-Alive

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Language: en-US,*

---

sample code -

```
QNetworkAccessManager* mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkRequest req;
req.setUrl(QUrl("sampleURL") );
mgr->get(req);
```

Result should be as below(with no authorization header) -

GET https://mywebsiteurl.com/remote.php/webdav/3.txt HTTP/1.1

---

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux) myapp/1.2.1

Connection: Keep-Alive

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Language: en-US,*

---

APIs like setHeader,setRawHeader are available but there is no way to completely remove a header.

Answer (score 0):

QT seems to handle authentication automatically through the signal/slot system, separate from the headers so you don't have to think about it.

Are you handling the authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply * reply, QAuthenticator * authenticator) signal from your NetworkManager.  If it's giving a false positive on an authentication request, you may be able to get around this by just resetting the authenticator in the signal.  Sorry this isn't a sure answer, but let me know if it works!

> This signal is emitted whenever a final server requests authentication
>   before it delivers the requested contents. The slot connected to this
>   signal should fill the credentials for the contents (which can be
>   determined by inspecting the reply object) in the authenticator
>   object.
>
> QNetworkAccessManager will cache the credentials internally and will
>   send the same values if the server requires authentication again,
>   without emitting the authenticationRequired() signal. If it rejects
>   the credentials, this signal will be emitted again.
>
> Note: It is not possible to use a QueuedConnection to connect to this
>   signal, as the connection will fail if the authenticator has not been
>   filled in with new information when the signal returns.
>
> See also proxyAuthenticationRequired().